# Proof from Boothby, exchanging order of partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open with $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^2$. Let $a \in U$. Show that

$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(a) = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}(a) $$

for all $i,j \in \{1, \dots, n\}.$

There are many proofs of this fact on various websites (some involve explicit limit calculations). However, I am interested in following a specific proof strategy that is devised in Boothby's *Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Differential Geometry*. Boothby begins by proving the following lemma:

Let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ be as above with $a \in U$. But assume further that $U$ is a star-shaped domain. If $|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}| < K$ on $U$, each $i$, then for all $x \in U$ we have $|f(x) - f(a)| \le K \sqrt{n} |x - a|$ (where $|x-a|$ is not absolute value, rather the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Boothby suggests that this lemma is key to proving the proposition above.

The first observation I have made is that, since we can restrict our attention to some ball centered at $a$, and compactly contained in $U$, we have no trouble assuming that $U$ is star-shaped and that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}, \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ are uniformly bounded on $U$.

I am also aware that, since we have continuity of the partial derivatives on $U$ (assuming now that $U$ is just a small ball centered at $a$), then $f$ and all the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ are *differentiable* on $U$. This means, that, for each $x \in U$ we have

$$f(x) - f(a) = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)(x_i - a_i) + |x - a|r(x,a),$$

and similarly for the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$, where $r(x,a)$ is a real-valued function of $x$ going to $0$ as $x \to a$.

I think that, to complete the proof, I will need to combine all of these ideas properly, but I haven't quite figured out how to do this yet. My guess is that I need to start with

$$\left|\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(a) - \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}(a)\right| \le \cdots$$

and then add and subtract the appropriate quantities, eventually showing this initial quantity is smaller than any positive number.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: $$f(a + h\cdot e_i + k\cdot e_j) - f(a + h\cdot e_i) - f(a + k\cdot e_j) + f(a)$$ Group two ways, and let $h,k \to 0$.